# What format is this scriptPubKey?

Tags: transactions, public-key, raw-transaction

I'm running BitcoinUnlimited's [giga_perf branch](https://github.com/BitcoinUnlimited/BitcoinUnlimited/tree/giga_perf) of bitcoin in regest mode, and I'm noticing a different format than P2PKH in the scriptPubKey when running listunspent over rpc.

Typically I see scriptPubKey's in the P2PKH format:

```
'76a914' + b58check_to_hex(address) + '88ac'
```

But with this implementation I'm seeing:

```
'2103' + ??? + 'ac'
```

Some examples below, what format are these scriptPubKey's in?

```
{
  "txid": "07ad742b0bab1c5e65fe720459747aa687d293fef0d0f168297bcaafbe73f17b",
  "vout": 0,
  "address": "mrjTCJGC7aYdZsy3gUJMpBesgtH1ymybsN",
  "scriptPubKey": "21031f5ce0854d50e632bd7002ae5aff977396376082e45329fcdf1af52ab68f766bac",
  "amount": 50.00000500,
  "confirmations": 101,
  "spendable": true
}, 
{
  "txid": "d7f623f59d8fa37eea5fafeb3819ecd76750bea9bb48d453e0eb13426c7e707e",
  "vout": 0,
  "address": "n2Faf95smgYu6e9aBVAwwzp6oULnL7SSSs",
  "scriptPubKey": "21039ff795e5433e67b418e100938ac72e2713a1661c15f48a5c198a5086d96285beac",
  "amount": 50.00000000,
  "confirmations": 108,
  "spendable": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are Pay to Pubkey scriptPubKeys. P2PK is in the format `<pubkey len> <pubkey> OP_CHECKSIG`. The `21` is the pubkey length and the `03` is the first byte of the pubkey. The `ac` is OP_CHECKSIG.

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I overlooked that.